# How to protect my email and social media accounts?

Tags: android, attack-prevention

Someone been hacking my account. It seems the person is expert hacker. I have had changed my password multiple times. They seems to know personal details of my life and things on my gmail and facebook account that very personal. I used a computer that someone installed teamviewer and logmein. I have increased the number of characters used in my account. I have in pass used unsecure wifi. I was trying figure out more methods to prevent this in the future.

Comment: Which operating system do you use (e.g. Windows / Linux / etc...)?  This will help in formulating a better answer.

Comment: Enable two factor authentication see http://www.pcworld.com/article/2036252/how-to-set-up-two-factor-authentication-for-facebook-google-microsoft-and-more.html

Answer (score 1):

Two step authentication, make it send a text to your phone anytime you need to login. check your logs on your computer and check all programs. run ccleaner, and malwarebytes.

Answer (score 1):

I see that there is the Android tag in the question, so if this is the only device you use, some of these steps will be not applicable to you (e.g. there would be no keyboard cord for someone to place a key logger on).  If you also own and use a PC, I would recommend performing all these steps on it.  Although I don't have the complete answer, the following should be a good start, and I welcome further elaboration / corrections:

- Check the event log on your computer for anything that appears out of the ordinary to try to figure out how you are being hacked.
- Make sure your antivirus software is up to date, and do a scan of your system to ensure you don't have malware on it that the hacker is using to retrieve your passwords.  It also good to do an "offline" scan, e.g. boot off a CD using Windows Defender Offline (assuming you have a PC with Windows), or use a similar product from a trusted vendor.
- Make sure you install the latest software updates, especially for your browser (which would be a likely attack vector).
- Make sure your firewall is on and configured properly.
- Physically inspect your system and see if anyone might have planted a key logger on it (especially on your keyboard cord) if applicable.  This is fairly unlikely, but possible.
- Change the security questions and answers (e.g. that are used for password resets) on the sites you use.
- Check your credit records with Transunion, Equifax, and Experian to ensure nothing out of the ordinary is going on.

  - If you do see things like extra accounts that you did not create, you are likely a victim of identity theft.  If you are in the United States, you should be able to use this site to help if you are an identity theft victim: https://www.identitytheft.gov/
- Once you are done with all the steps you can complete above for your device(s), change the passwords again, and be on the lookout for further malicious activity (hopefully these measures will stop it).